# MATLAB "back slash" computation

Tags: matrices, matlab, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I am looking at a MATLAB code that times the backslash operator for several cases. I will list the cases below:

Note: all of these are for m = 5000

1) 
Z = randn(m,m); A = Z'*Z; b = randn(m,1);
tic; x = A\b; toc;
**elapsed time = 1.0368**

2)
tic; x= A\b; toc;
**elapsed time = 1.0303**

3) 
A2 = A; A2(m,1) = A2(m,1)/2;
tic; x = A2\b; toc;
**elapsed time = 2.0361**

Note that the times above were obtained years ago and today's MATLAB is significantly faster, but the relative trends are still observed.

FOr each case, I would like to know why the experiment was performed and why is the result the way it is. The first 2 are fairly simple and the elapsed times are approximately the same. But in #3, we see the time double. For #3, the lower left element of the matrix is divided by 2, but any idea why this would result in a two times slower computation?

Comment: I don't know the internals of Matlab's backslash operator, but it may have something to do with the fact that `A` is symmetric while `A2` is not.

Comment: Hmm you're right. I need to look into what the backslash does.

Comment: you would have a better chance on http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/

Comment: I strongly disagree with the closing votes: this question clearly belongs to MSE, since the observed timings are related to the numerical algorithms used, which fall into **numerical analysis**, which is indeed a field of mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm used by the **mldivide** operator is descried here in Matlab's documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html

The "general" backslash for square matrices would end up using [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), while for symmetric matrices the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) is used instead. This decomposition, which is simply a simplification of LU for symmetric matrices, is also twice as fast, which explains your timings.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Computation